# Multiple aggregate functions in Hibernate Query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, aggregate

I want to have an HQL query which essentially does this :

```
select quarter, sum(if(a>1, 1, 0)) as res1, sum(if(b>1, 1, 0)) as res2 from foo group by quarter;
```

I want a List as my output list with `Summary Class ->`

```
Class Summary
{
long res1;
long res2;
int quarter;
}
```

How can I achieve this aggregation in HQL? What will be the hibernate mappings for the target Object?
I don't want to use SQL kind of query that would return `List<Object[]>` and then transform it to `List<Summary>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Summary` is not an entity, you don't need a mapping for it, you can create an appropriate constructor and use an HQL constructor expression instead. Aggregate functions and `if`s are also possible, though you need to use `case` syntax instead of `if`.

So, if `Foo` is an entity mapped to the table `Foo` it would look like this:

```
select new Summary(
    f.quarter,
    sum(case when f.a > 1 then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case when f.b > 1 then 1 else 0 end)
) from Foo f group by f.quarter
```

**See also:**

- [Chapter 16. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible with a subselect in the mapping. Have a look at [More complex association mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-complex) in the hibernate documentation. I've never tried that possibility.

But even the hibernate guys recommend "*... but it is more practical to handle these kinds of cases using HQL or a criteria query.*" That's what I would do: Use the group-by in the HQL statement and work with the List. The extra time for copying this list into a list of suitable objects is negligible compared with the time which the group-by is using in the database. But it seems you don't like this possibility.

A third possibility is to define a view in the database containing your group-by and then create a normal mapping for this view.